# Can't seem to get http get parameters sent from my Android app to display on my PHP page

Tags: java, php, android, apache, http

I can't seem to get my PHP page to display the data I have sent using a http client in Android. All I need now is displaying it in PHP which seems to be a challenge, I know I have done something wrong.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.  I have tried everything from `var_dump($_SERVER)` to `json_decode` to display it in PHP. Is it even possible to display it on a PHP page?

```
     private class Connection extends AsyncTask{
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects){
        try{
            PostData(R.id.fullscreen_content, 3);
           }
                catch(IOException exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
}            

protected void PostData(Integer Question_ID,Integer ResponseChosen_ID)        {

       URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:443/SwlLogin.php");
        HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet post = new HttpGet(conn.getURL().toString());
        post.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");

        conn.connect();
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.UK);
        SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss",Locale.UK);

        String nowDate = dt.format(date);
        String nowTime = time.format(date);

        String phpDate = nowDate;
        String phpTime = nowTime;


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Question ID", Question_ID.toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Response_Chosen_ID", ResponseChosen_ID.toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TimestampDate", phpDate));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", phpTime));

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        array.put(params);
        post.setHeader("postData", params.toString());
        post.getParams().setParameter("JSON", params);
        HttpParams var = httpClient.getParams();
        var.setParameter("GET",params);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
        OutputStreamWriter write = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            builder.append(line);
        }
        Log.d("Response:", builder.toString());
        builder.toString();
        reader.close();

 public void happy_click(View view) throws IOException {
    try{
        new Connection().execute();
        report_success();
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
        messageBox("Response was not successful","Failed to process response" + exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: is this on the UI thread? is the app crashing?

Comment: yes the app is crashing and it is on the UI thread is that the reason?. But the http request should still get executed right?

Comment: I don't develop with Android, but I believe people will ask you for your stack trace, and they will say that you should not be doing network operations in the UI thread.

Comment: the stack trace is : Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: that is a threading issue, can you post the whole code up here

Comment: what i have written should work right?

Comment: is it even possible to do what i am trying to by sending some data to a php page? as im now using loopj and its executing the request successfully but i cant get anything on the other end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not run this code on the UI thread or you will get a NetworkRequestOnUIThread exception. you have to do this on a different thread.

try using AsyncTask via

```
 private class Uploader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
     protected void doInBackground(){
        // do network request here
      }
     private void onPostExecute(){
        // handle UI updates here as is on ui Thread
     }
 }
```

or you could look at using OkHTTP library which I recommend highly. to do this download the jar from [okHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp). add it to you libs folder then you can do network call like this

```
  MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    JSONObject parcel = new JSONObject();
    try{
        parcel.put("email", emailEdit.getText().toString());
        parcel.put("password", passwordEdit.getText().toString());
        parcel.put("device", "Android");
        parcel.put("hash", "1234");;
    }catch (JSONException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, parcel.toString());
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .url("YOURURL")
            .post(body)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            if (null != e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (null != response && response.message().equals(Constants.KEY_OK)) {
                JSONObject serverResponse;
                try{
                    serverResponse = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    if(serverResponse.getBoolean(Constants.KEY_SUCCESS)){
                        Constants.getInstance().setToken(serverResponse.getString(Constants.KEY_TOKEN));
                       moveToHomePage();
                    }else{
                        showLoginFail();
                    }

                }catch (JSONException e ){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                response.body().close();
            } else {
                showLoginFail();
            }
        }
    });
```

also make sure you have

```
 <uses-permission android:name="...permision.INTERNET">
```

in your manifest file

Comment: Yes i have the internet permissions and this is using the async task class ie:

Comment: the stack trace is what i am getting:: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: is okHTTP guranteed to do what i want also what i have should work right?

Comment: it is alot easier than AsyncTasks

Comment: sorry but can you explain a bit further please?

Comment: can i just get a JAR and use it that way rather than building it through maven?